# Rails 3 - Devise with acts_as_audited possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, acts-as-audited

I'd like to use Devise with `acts_as_audited`.
I have googled it, but the results weren't very clear.
What are its pros and cons?

Answer (score 0):

I use [Paper Trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) here which is newer but much the same thing, and the top of my Devise User model looks like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_paper_trail
```

And now I have a growing `versions` table in my DB with a row for every CRUD action on the User model.

The benefits are that all previous versions of your model's data are saved and stored in YAML, allowing you to rollback/undo.

The cons? Only database size and perhaps a small performance hit at Write/Update time.